# SSIS conditional split into different flat file destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to create a conditional split SSIS package where I want to send the content to different files based on the following conditions

Case 1: If all values in Column A is 0, send it to FlatFileDestination1
Case 2: If at least one value of column A is non-zero, send it to FlatFileDestination2.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the data coming from, a SQL table?

Comment: @Larnu, The data is coming from SQL server table.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to check if at least one row has a value in a dataset isn't what a conditional split is for. A Condition Split is be splitting individual rows to separate places.

What you could do, however, is add an additional column to your initial dataset which counts of number of non-0 values:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN [Column A] != 1 THEN 1 END) OVER () AS ColumnANonZero
```

Then, in your dataflow, split rows that have a value of 0 for `ColumnANonZero` to `FlatFileDestination1` in the Conditional Split.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Since there should be either case one or case two, it is giving me the following error.   [Flat File Destination 2 [49]] Warning: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Seems like the error is telling you the problem, and it has nothing to do with the answer I've given @AiE .

Answer (score 0):

I think I would handle it this way:

Add a column to your data source via this query:

```
;with cte as
(
    --Put your query in here
)

select cte.*
    ,BoolTest = case when ColATest.num >0 then 1 else 0 end 
from cte 
cross apply (select SUM(ABS(ColumnA)) from cte) as ColATest(num)
```

This will add a 1 or 0 to each row to be used as a conditional split value. A 1 will have at least one row with a non-zero value and a 0 means that ther eare no rows without a 0.

Comment: Thank you KeithL for the suggestion. I agree with you adding another column. There is another issue when I am doing that. Since the file name of the destination flat file is the same on both cases, its is giving me the following error massage. [Flat File Destination 2 [49]] Warning: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. I want only create one file based on the condition.

Comment: let me give you another way.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

execute SQL before dataflow:

```
;with cte as
(
    --Put your query in here
)

select Test = SUM(ABS(ColumnA)) from cte)
```

Save that into a variable called Test (choose a number datatype).

Step 2:
Add an expression to the flat file destination for connection string. Make sure to set delay validation to true.

```
@Test > 0 ? [put in your full path for not 0 here as a string] : [put in your full path for colA =0 here]
```

You should be able to leave your data flow alone (AKA no conditional split). Basically, source straight to destination and the expression dictates where the file ends up.